How to return a Ok response from an Ocelot API gateway but then forward the request downstream for further processing?
I am trying to implement an Ocelot gateway application and I am facing an issue that I appreciate any suggestions.

Under normal operation, WITHOUT THE GATEWAY, the upstream app (the client) posts a request and only expects a payload validation response.

The downstream app (the server) validates the payload and immediately returns an OK/Error synchronous response (payload validation results, ok or not ok).

The downstream app THEN processes the payload in the BACKGROUND and sends a reponse (later) to the client through a web hook.



If I now introduce Ocelot API gateway in the middle,
A. I want to do the payload validations in the gateway itself and at once return OK/Error to the upstream client.
B. THEN, I want to forward the request the downstream server. Downstream server will simply return OK which I should ignore (not pass on upstream.)
I can do step A above and abort and not return Error if the payload has error. But if the payload has no error, I cannot figure out how to do step B, how to pass it downstream AFTER I have returned Ok/Error response to upstream app.
On top of this, this may depend on the particular route. In some routes default Ocelot behavior will be fine, but in other routes I will have issue mentioned above.

Sorry I don't have any code to post. I understand Ocelot has its own middleware configurations but can they be used to solve this issue?
